# mysqlfailover command gives Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, linux, replication, failover

I am trying to run mysqlfailover using workbench console:

```
 mysqlfailover --master=root@localhost:3306 --discover-slaves-login='root' --log=log.txt
```

and I am getting the error :

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to the master server.
Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I tried to google but found nothing.
Mysql version is 5.6.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is simply saying that user root@localhost is not allowed to execute this command with no password. If you have the password set for root@user modify you command as " mysqlfailover --master=root:**YOURMYSQLPASSWORDFORROOT**@localhost:3306 --discover-slaves-login='root' --log=log.txt"

This should solve the problem.

Comment: thank you it solved my problem. but now getting other error but will now from here.